# How to use another type of id in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

The task is to change default unique `_id` in mongoDb to autoincremented id with that kind of view `00001`, `00002`, I have done only autoincrement like that `1`, `2` , but not sure is that way right or no

here is my autoincrement code:

```js
//here we sort by id and found the last added product
const lastProd = await this.productModel
      .findOne()
      .sort({ _id: 'desc' })
      .exec();
 
 
    const newProduct = new this.productModel({
    //if last prod is not null, do increment
      _id: lastProd ? lastProd._id + 1 : 0,
      title,
      description: desc,
      price,
      image:image.filename,
    });
    const result = await newProduct.save();
```

photo of result of my code

[image]

Comment: The `_id` of a document is automatically set by mongoDB, it's a hexadecimal value, and I don't think it can be incremented.

Comment: @Gabriel Lupu, I have tested my example of code, and it works, the problem is that I have no idea about is the way of my realization right and how to bring it to this view ```00001```

Comment: [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_autoincrement_sequence.htm#:~:text=MongoDB%20does%20not%20have%20out,to%20uniquely%20identify%20the%20documents.) a tutorial on autoincrement in mongodb

Comment: Okay, so you are inserting your own id, why do you need all those zeros before 1?

Comment: because of the task requirements

Comment: Do you have to see this in some response to a query (inside the UI for example) or directly inside mongoDB documents?

Comment: have added the screen to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB will not let you save prop with type `number` that starts with a bunch of zeros.

I would save the id as type string & when working with it convert it to a number, and saving it back in mongoDB as a string (if really necessary).

```js
const parseIdFromNumber = id => {
  if (id < 10) return `000${id}`;
  if (id < 100) return `00${id}`;
  if (id < 1000) return `0${id}`;
}

const a = parseIdFromNumber(4);
const b = parseIdFromNumber(22);
const c = parseIdFromNumber(233);

// save to db
console.log(a, b, c)
// converting string ids to numbers
console.log(+a, +b, +c)
```

In conclusion save your ids as strings with the extra zeros, when working with them convert them to numbers and before saving into DB back to strings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as I understand, mongoDB/mongoose don't have its functionality for realize the task, I should do it by writing my own code in js, please let me know, is that right?

Comment: Yes, mongoDB will not let you add a number starting with a bunch of zeros. If you need further clarification, let me know.